# How to connect 2 SSH clients through a SSH server?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Hi I want to remotely administer (command line interface) a linux box from my home Windows PC.

I have an ssh client on the linux box.  I have an ssh client on my home Windows PC.  I have a login on a VPS running an ssh server.  I am able to ssh from the linux box to the VPS.  I am able to ssh from my home Windows PC to the VPS.

How do I connect the two ssh clients?  Is there an easy way to connect the ports locally (on the VPS/ssh server)?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: I have a problem understanding what you mean with `How do I connect the two ssh clients?`. My first guess would be that both client see the same thing. In which case screen or tmux is the answer.

Comment: I want the Windows PC at home to have a command line interface (terminal) to the linux box.  In order to reach it, I need to go through the VPSbox, and I want to use SSH so the connection is secure.    So the Windows PC (ssh client) will open a SSH connection to the VPS box, and then I need to open a connection to reach the linux box.  In order to access the linux box, the ssh connection has to be initiated by the linux box. (to the VPS server)

Comment: How exactly are you initiating the ssh connection from the linux box?

Answer (score 1):

depends if the logins are just one-way as you describe them. If that's the case, you have the option of a remote port forward (of the 22 of linbox) to a free port on the VPS (say 22222)

```
LINbox> ssh -vfN -R *:22222:localhost:22 VPSuser@VPSbox
```

(the * is default bind, you can specify an IP if you need to)

you can then login from win `WINbox> ssh LINuser@VPSbox -p 22222`

this has a quirk - you have to setup a script which monitors the tunnel is still up, or that can restart it (because it *will* brake down ;) and that may require a pubkey so you can do it without entering a password

seel also [Forwarding Specific Ports through SSH Reverse Tunnels](https://superuser.com/questions/303400/forwarding-specific-ports-through-ssh-reverse-tunnels)

Comment: Yes it can be one way, since I'm doing the administration from the Windows PC.  In fact, I can have the linux box know when I want to contact it, so it could initiate its ssh connection to the VPS server.    I'll study the ssh commands you listed so I understand how they work, and give it a shot.  many thanks

Comment: one more thing - check that VPSBox sshd_config has `GatewayPorts` set to _yes_ or _clientspecified_. Otherwise the tunnel will not accept remote clients (only local from VPS)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is reverse ssh tunneling with a machine acting as a middleman.

You should follow rogerovo's hint and create the [port forwarding](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) from the VPS (some random high port) to the LinuxBox (port 22). However you will also need a **SSHD server** running on the LinuxBox.

Only having two clients is not going to work. A client coming from the LinuxBox, cannot take a command from the VPS back to the LinuxBox. You need a server on the LinuxBox that actually receives and handles commands.

Otherwise:
Breaking tunnels -> You better take a look at the [keep alive](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/) option
Second tunnel -> To simplify logging in you could add another tunnel from the Windows Box to the VPS.

(Win 22222 -> VPS 22221 -> VPS 22222 -> LinuxBox 22)

Then you need to login only once to reach the linux box. No idea however how to do port forwarding from Windows :/.