# Reverse Proxy, Port Forwarding for passing on Reverse SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I'm trying to access a webpage hosted on a device from an AWS public URL. The catch is this device's IP is not public. I am able to issue a command to the device locally (ssh -i path/to/Cert -R 19999:localhost:80 ubuntu@my.amazonaws.com) to reverse SSH from the device to AWS. From there I can curl/reach the page in AWS via 127.0.0.1:19999. Now I'm trying to figure out how can I make a http request to AWS and forward to the already forwarded device. I've tried setting some IP Forwarding rules like:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --dst 127.0.0.1 ip tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 19999
```

I'v also tried running lighttpd to reverse proxy with:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/admin" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "127.0.0.1:19999" )
    url.redirect-code = 302
  }
}
```

However, neither seem to work. I'm not sure if there is something else I need in my SSH .conf to allow the forwarding further or what else I can/should do to get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added `GatewayPorts yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and can now access it over http.

Admin can close as duplicate sorry.

[Forwarding Specific Ports through SSH Reverse Tunnels](https://superuser.com/questions/303400/forwarding-specific-ports-through-ssh-reverse-tunnels?rq=1)